# RefineryCMS trying to tweak layout per page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, refinerycms

I'm new to RefineryCMS and still pretty new to rails as well. What i'm trying to do, is use the same header and footer in my layout file and then in the dynamic section that gets pulled from the CMS database, use different markup per page.

Example template:

```
<header>
...
</header>

# want to insert "home" page or "about" page here depending on url.

<footer>
...
</footer>
```

Example of what i want home page to have inserted into template:

```
<div>
  <%= raw @page.content_for(:body) %>
</div>
```

Example of what i want about page to have inserted into template:

```
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <%= raw @page.content_for(:body) %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can i change the markup per page without having to add the markup in the wysiwyg editor in the CMS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Which version are you using?

If you're using 2.0.x, then there are two options inside `config/initializers/refinery/pages.rb` — the first one should be `config.view_template_whitelist`, and the second one should be `config.use_view_templates`.

For `config.view_template_whitelist`, you can specify an array of symbols that match to views inside your `app/views/refinery/pages/` folder (i.e. if you have `about_us.html.erb`, you would whitelist [:about_us], just as you might if you were going to say `render :about_us` inside your controller.

`config.use_view_templates` simply needs to be set to true to enable the dropdown in the backend that will let you choose a template from your whitelist.

If you're curious, there also exists `config.layout_template_whitelist` and `config.use_layout_template` options too that do the same, but with layouts.

Comment: Ok i'm going for the `view_template_whitelist` option and what do need to put in my template to pull in the code from my file in /app/views/refinery/pages? If i put `<%= yield %>`, it pulls in the content from the database.

Comment: i got it. I didn't realize i had to set config.use_view_templates as well as config.view_template_whitelist. The way you wrote it i understood it as i had 2 options - one or the other. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Ah, sorry for the delay – I was away for the weekend. For future reference, I did up a guide. Can you [take a gander](https://github.com/resolve/refinerycms/blob/master/doc/guides/3%20-%20Advanced%20Techniques%20and%20Tips/3%20-%20Using%20Custom%20View%20or%20Layout%20Templates.textile) and let me know if it helps you understand the process a bit better?

Comment: Very in-depth and it looks to be very good. Some of it is still above my rails skills so i don't follow it all, but the first stuff looks very helpful. Definitely wouldn't hurt to have a link to that on the refinery site!

Comment: I changed the blog and news page css and the homepage also changed accordingly , as both the engines use default refinery layout . Im confused how to keep the changes specific to blog and news pages :'(

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to change the header rather than the whole layout then you can override the `_header` partial:

```
cp  /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/refinerycms-core-2.0.6/app/views/refinery/_header.html.erb  app/views/refinery/_header.html.erb
```

..and then edit `app/views/refinery/_header.html.erb` and restart the application ( if required).

This allowed me to place a header image above the nav menu without creating a custom layout.