# Customize site layout with Refinery CMS

Tags: refinerycms

New with Rails and with RefineryCMS.  I came across this[question about per page layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827416/refinerycms-trying-to-tweak-layout-per-page).

It pointed me to [a very nice guide](https://github.com/resolve/refinerycms/blob/master/doc/guides/3%20-%20Advanced%20Techniques%20and%20Tips/3%20-%20Using%20Custom%20View%20or%20Layout%20Templates.textile) and in this guide it says

> In this case, when we are customizing the rendering of only the page,
>   not the header or footer or actual site layout, it is appropriate to enable
>   Refinery’s custom view templates.

My question is the one this guide leaves out:  how do you customize the rendering of the header and footer with templates in Refinery CMS?  Where is documentation for that?  Thanks all!

Answer (score 2):

For customizing anything outside of the page content, you have to override refinery views.

In terminal:

```
rake refinery:override view=refinery/_footer
```

This is covered in this refinery guide: http://refinerycms.com/guides/overriding-views

Comment: thanks, but that only allows one definition of how the footer renders.
what I wound up doing was bringing in all the partials with this command:  rake refinery:override view=refinery/*

Comment: I get what you wanted to do, now. Overriding all the views is a good way to get to know refinery, but for a production app it makes upgrading to a newer refinery version trickier. When you update, I don't think your overridden views get updated.  I'm told that if you delete the override view files, they default back to the ones in the refinery gem.  I'd recommend that for anything you don't customize.

Comment: I changed the blog and news page css and the homepage also changed accordingly , as both the engines use default refinery layout . Im confused how to keep the changes specific to blog and news pages :'(